# How to set Routes company dependent in Multi-Company env in Odoo 17?

Tags: odoo, odoo-17, multi-company

I have enabled Multi company in Odoo 17 and created 4 companies and installed sales, purchase, accounting and Manufacturing module. By default all these modules and its features are available in all companies. But in my case the production (manufacturing) only happens in one company ( lets say Company 4).

And all the products and customers are shared in all companies. I want to generate a Manufacturing Order when i confirm a Sales Order, so set the route as `manufacture` instead `Buy`. Its working fine, but it works for all companies, that means when i create and confirm a SO in Company 1 it generates a MO ( this shouldn't happen).

So i added `_check_company_auto`, `company_dependent` to the model `product.template` and the field `route_ids` to make it company dependent.

But it didn't work. when i change the route ids it gets update in all companies.
How can i implement this?
Here is my code,

```
        from odoo import fields,api,models,_

        class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
            _inherit = 'product.template'
            _check_company_auto = True

            route_ids = fields.Many2many(
                'stock.route', 'stock_route_product', 'product_id', 'route_id', 'Routes',
                domain=[('product_selectable', '=', True)],
                check_company = True,company_dependent = True,
                help="Depending on the modules installed, this will allow you to define the route of the product: whether it will be bought, manufactured, replenished on order, etc.")
```